# Create a list of pairs from a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm new to Lisp and have no idea how to write this...

```
You give: ("Test" "TEST" "third" "the last")
You get:  (("A" . "Test") ("B" . "TEST") ("C" . "third") ("D" . "the last"))
Function: (defun choices (&rest choices))
```

In C, I can just write a `for` for this, but Lisp can't +1 to string and loop doesn't have a counter, either... Could someone please give me a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
(defun  choices (&rest choices)
  (loop for i from 1 to 26
        and item in choices
        collect (cons (string (digit-char (+ 9 i) 36))
                      item)))
```

The above code has no error checking for more than 26 choices (and you
didn't specify how to handle them if it's not an error).

You could use [`CHAR-CODE`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_char_c.htm) and [`CODE-CHAR`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_code_c.htm) to "increment a character",
but the encoding they provide is not standardized (only some
properties of it are guaranteed). With [`DIGIT-CHAR`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_digit_.htm) in radix 36, we're
guaranteed to get the English alphabet (uppercase) for weights 10 to
35.

And of course, [`LOOP`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) has a lot of things, including whatever counters you want.

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thanks for both your sample and explanation :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate two lists in the way you described by simply doing mapcar+cons:

```
(mapcar #'cons '("A" "B" "C" "D") '("Test" "TEST" "third" "the last"))
; => (("A" . "Test") ("B" . "TEST") ("C" . "third") ("D" . "the last"))
```

Since the second list is given, now the problem is only in generating the ABCD list. That can be achieved with loop and code-char:

```
(loop for i from 65 to 68 collect (string (code-char i)))
; => ("A" "B" "C" "D")
```

Combining those two into an answer and tailoring it to your specific problem should be easy now.